# Overriding Methods with no Implementation

Tags: c#, xna, overriding

So I have a class that derives from [GameComponent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamecomponent.aspx). Inside the class this method is present:

```
public override void Initialize(){
     base.Initialize();
}
```

I've seen multiple sources where people do the same thing, they override the Initialize method but have no implementation except the `base.Initialize` call of course. I don't understand this because why have the method if it doesn't do anything? If you don't include the overriding method the virtual method inside the GameComponent class will get called by default right? I literally took out the whole method and nothing different happened.

To put this short what is the point of overriding methods that have no implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you show is exactly equivalent to not having overridden it at all; Resharper will in fact suggest deleting such a method, since it is unnecessary clutter.

To be technical, overriding it and just calling the base method is not 'no implementation', it's the default implementation, or no additional implementation. No implementation would be overridding it and then blanking the method:

```
public override void Initialize()
{
   // no implementation
}
```

You wouldn't want to do that in this case, but there are cases where you might want to.

Answer (score 0):

None.

The reason is that the GameComponent template includes it to guide you about how should be implmented.